# dllimport or dllexport for class declaration with base class dllimport

Tags: c++, mingw, shared-libraries, dllimport, dllexport

I have a class with some static member function in it. Let say class `B`, This class has a base class which comes form a thirdparty library say A. Now class `A` has declared with `dllimport` and with `mingw` I can build sharedlibs or that class without any trouble. The build goes on fine on other platforms which obviously don't need to deal with import/export stuff.

```
// export and imports and properly defined. 
#define IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

Class IMPORT A {

public:


static staticOfA();

};

class EXPORT B : public A{

public:

...
static staticOfB()
};
```

Now this gives me undefined reference when during linking dll. The undefined reference error implicate both static and non-static methods of class `B`.

Can anyone tell why?.

If the above information is not sufficient, please ask and i could provide them.

Comment: did you compile the lib with mingw and now you're trying to link it into an application compiled with another toolset ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, that doesn't look good.  You always need macaroni in the .h file since the class needs to be *exported* when you build the DLL but needs to be *imported* when the .h file is used in client code.

The standard pattern is:

```
#ifdef BUILDING_FOO
#define EXPORTED __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORTED __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class EXPORTED A {
   // etc..
};
```

And you define BUILDING_FOO only when you build the DLL.

I can't really tell what you intended to do with class B.  If it *really* should be imported then it belongs in another .h file for another DLL project.

Comment: This is the way i actually defined export but for the sample purpose i wrote it like '//export and imports and properly defined.'. Class B is  built in a dll which contains many other classes. And other clasess apart from B which are marked as EXPORTED in ok when building an application. Only for Class B, I am having undefined error and the difference is both class A and B have static members and A is using dllimport

Comment: This all makes little sense to me.  Pretty important to create a .h file that is #included both in the source code files for the DLL as well as the client code.  Only way to make sure that the client uses the exact same definition as the DLL.  You get linker errors when you forget to link the import library of the DLL.

Comment: I dont understand this. I have the include file for class A in class B's .h file. When i tried no import/export in class B. there was no link problem. Does this make sense?.